# JQuery ajax for pdf loading in object tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm embedding a PDF in a web page with the following html

```
   <object id="pdf" classid="clsid:CA8A9780-280D-11CF-A24D-444553540000" width="1024"
        height="600">
        <param name="SRC" value="/GetDoc.ashx?SOID=<%=Html.Encode(Model.OrderID)%>" />
        <embed src="/GetDoc.ashx?SOID=<%=Html.Encode(Model.OrderID)%>  "
            width="1024" height="600">                          
    </embed>
    </object>
```

The PDF's can be a little slow to load so I'd like to hide the object and display a loading message / gif until it's fully loaded so the user isn't looking at a blank screen.

can someone suggest a way to do this using jquery ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code works.

```
<div style="background: transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat">
<object height="1250px" width="100%" type="application/pdf" data="aaa.pdf">
    <param value="aaa.pdf" name="src"/>
    <param value="transparent" name="wmode"/>
</object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could display a placeholder div and hide the PDF object until it has fully loaded. I am not sure if the `load` event works, however, I have never used it:

```
<div id="pdf-placeholder" style="width: 1024px; height: 600px;">
    <!-- whatever you want here -->
</div>
<object id="pdf" style="display: none;" ...>
   ...
</object>

// JS code
$(window).load( function() {
    $('#pdf-placeholder').hide();
    $('#pdf').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of discussion on doing something once a PDF is downloaded.  The strategies presented depend an event when the plug-in has loaded loaded its content.  It seems the combination of Adobe Reader and Internet Explorer don't give us this event.

Could we use XMLHttpRequest to download the PDF content first, putting it into browser cache but not actually displaying it, and when that's done tell the browser to show the object?